# display the element on the php side only in one instance

Tags: php

I have a list of items and on the php side I display it in multiple views depending on the content using a single list page

Here is an example

```
<div class="list">
  <?= $this->render('list', ['items' => $itemsA, 'priority' => true]) ?>
  <?= $this->render('list', ['items' => $itemsB, 'priority' => true]) ?>
  <?= $this->render('list', compact('items')) ?>
</div>
```

The list page itself

```
<?php if (isset($priority)) { ?>
  <div class="title">Priority</div>
<?php } else { ?>
  <div class="title">All</div>
<?php } ?>
<?php foreach ($items as $item) { ?>
  <div class="name"><?= $item->name ?></div>
  <div class="description"><?= $item->description ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

As a result, my page looks like this

```
Priority

Item name
Item Description

Priority

Item name
Item Description

All

Item name
Item Description
```

Now I have every render has a title.
But is it possible to make sure that there is only one Priority title? It is also necessary that this title be specified on the list page.

Comment: First we have to assume that you have the array sorted so that the priorities are consecutive. Otherwise there will need to be additional updates to your array. After that, there will most likely need to be one additional variable. That variable will need to tell the system if priority has already been displayed. Unless that is what `$priority` was meant for

Comment: @imvain2 everything is fine with arrays, the only question is not to duplicate the title for priority

Comment: What is the `render` function? Is it relevant here? What are the values for `$priority` and `$items`? Please provide examples. Or even better: share an example from https://3v4l.org/ or https://onlinephp.io/

Comment: The short answer is NO. You need an additional state variable to remember what you did last time.  It's not hard.  I suppose you could also add a ``title'=>false` parameter, and have it default to true.

Comment: @TimRoberts how about an additional state variable?

Comment: All you need is a class variable that tells you which header the last run printed, and if this run has the same header, don't print it.  You would need 3 states: nothing printed, last was "priority", last was "all".

Answer (score 0):

So, create `$this->last = 0;` in your initialization.  Then:

```
<?php if (isset($priority) && $this->last != 1) { ?>
  <div class="title">Priority</div>
<?php } else if (!isset($priority) && $this->last != 2) { ?>
  <div class="title">All</div>
<?php } ?>
<?php foreach ($items as $item) { ?>
  <div class="name"><?= $item->name ?></div>
  <div class="description"><?= $item->description ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

And be sure to add this AFTER the code above:

```
$this->last = isset($priority)? 1 : 2;
```

Comment: I got it like this: All - item, All - item, item. That is, the All title was displayed for both priority, but nothing was displayed for all

Comment: I did make a mistake here which I will fix, but it looks like you set `$this->last` BEFORE the HTML section.  You have to set it AFTER you use it.

Comment: I didn’t quite understand where I should declare `$this->last = 0;`, since now this variable is reset to zero when loading each render

Comment: You put it in the class constructor, where you initialize the rest of the fields.  You must have some function where you do one-time initialization.